# Google API, drive.files.list and returning child files only

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the '[googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)' library in NodeJS and I am trying to return the list of files and folders in the currently specified folder, but instead I find `drive.files.list` returns all files that the user has been granted permissions to read.

My goal is to be able to download the folder structure below a given folder, that then could be consumed by the NodeJS application in a meaningful way.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const google = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
const key = require('./key.json');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  key.client_email,
  null,
  key.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  null
);

const drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: jwtClient
});

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  // Make an authorized request to list Drive files.
  drive.files.list({
     includeRemoved: false,
     spaces: 'drive',
     fileId: 'the-file-id-of-the-folder'
  }, function (err, resp) {
    if (!err) {
        var i;
        var files = resp.files;
        for (i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].mimeType !== 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder') {
                console.log('file: ' + files[i].name);
            } else {
                console.log('directory: ' + files[i].name);
            }
            console.log(files[i]);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
  });
});
```

Note I did try the `drive.files.get` endpoint, without the `alt: 'media'` parameter, but it does not seem to return any more metadata that the `drive.files.list` call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Further exploration leads to the '[Search Parameters'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) page, which indicates in v3 of the API there is also the 'fields' and 'q' parameters, such that, the list operations becomes (ES6 code):

```
var fileId = '0B0gSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXb0hpaWM'
drive.files.list({
    includeRemoved: false,
    spaces: 'drive',
    fileId: fileId,
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, mimeType, modifiedTime)',
    q: `'${fileId}' in parents`
}, function (err, response) {
   // TODO handle response
});
```

Note, for other metadata, see:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource